# Download email attachments from outlook for only today's sent date with specific subjects

Tags: outlook

I am looking for a macro code that would download the attachments only from emails sent as of today's date and with certain specific subjects only. i managed to find the general code for downloading attachments but can you please tell me how i can i add the filter for only downloading attachments sent on today's date and restrict the search to only the required subjects? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Items.Restrict method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869597.aspx

If you post your code, I will take a look.